# Angular file upload SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm trying to make a file upload working in a angular project with a node server

Angular:

```
public uploadFile(file: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.api_url + '/upload', formData);
  }
```

Nodejs

```
function upload(req, res){
  var dir = __dirname +'/../uploaded';
  var fileDir;
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }
  var form = new IncomingForm({ uploadDir: __dirname + '/../uploaded' });
  let readStream;
  form.on('file', (field, file) => {
    fs.renameSync(file.path, file.path + '_' + file.name);
    fileDir = file.path + '_' + file.name;
    fileDir = fileDir.replace(__dirname, '');
  });
  form.on('end', () => {
    dirname = path.join(__dirname, '/../uploaded');
    fileDir = fileDir.replace(dirname + '\\', '');
    fileDir = fileDir.replace('/app/src/uploaded/', '');
    return res.status(200).json({ 'file': fileDir }).end();
  });
  form.parse(req);
}
```

When I submit a form I get the error :

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I can't find the source of the problem I tried different approaches on the client side and the server side. There is a problem with the JSON data but I don't have a way to modify it with this file upload,

Hope anybody has a solution

Comment: where do you get that error, on browser, on server?

Comment: The client does not give an error,  it appears in the node console

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: Sorry for comming back so late tot this toppic but hopes it maybe dan stille help you or somebody else. In my node application I used body parser json to parse the incomming data to json ofcourse formdata with files isnt json so it fixed it for me to create an endpoint for uploads before i parse the request to json

Comment: I also found an option to send a file in json then you have to Read the file contents in angular and convert it to Base64 encoding and add it to the json you send, on the node server your convert it back. But I found that option more a hassel

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the above code by placing this line of code

```
form.parse(req);
```

after this line

```
var form = new IncomingForm({ uploadDir: __dirname + '/../uploaded' });
```